# remove multiple specific items from array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
let arr = ['liverpool', 'arsenal', 'man utd', 'chelsea', 'tottenham', 'crystal palace', 'madrid', 'barcelona'];
```

and I want to remove items, let's say `'arsenal'` and `'chelsea'`, but this needs to be dynamic.

I have tried the following, where `items` is an array but unfortunately it didn't work:

```
function removeItems(items) {
   arr.filter(item => {
      return !arr.includes(items)
   });
}

removeItems(['arsenal', 'chelsea']);
```

Comment: is items an array?

Comment: @RohitKashyap sorry was just updating the question

Comment: why const ... don't you think it should be var

Comment: @mohitesachin217 updated

Comment: `filter` returns a **new** array, it doesn't modify the array you call it on. So `removeItem` would need to return the result, and the call would have to assign the result to something.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did see that but this is a bit different as it is multiple items

Comment: @peterflanagan - Yes, it is. I've also added a more specific one. Frankly, this could also have been closed as "typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future." This isn't worth a discussion. See above for what to do. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
function removeItems(items) {
   return arr.filter(item => {
      return !items.includes(item)
   });
}

const newArr = removeItems(['arsenal', 'chelsea']);
```

Comment: No, see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714020/remove-multiple-specific-items-from-array#comment101870206_57714020).

Comment: arr.filter returns the new array, not mutates it, edited

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much for your help, answer makes sense.